# md-datepicker forcing to input value

Tags: angularjs, datepicker, angular-material

i have simple angular application, contain date picker of material input.

```
<form name="xyz" ng-submit="xyz.$valid && submitMyForm()">
    <md-input-container class="md-block">
        <label>Available From</label>
        <md-datepicker
            ng-model="user.availableFrom"
            ng-required="false"
            md-open-on-focus
            name="availableFrom"
            id="availableFrom">
        </md-datepicker>
    </md-input-container>
    <input type="Submit" value="Submit">
</form>
```

when i click on submit button then it shows red underline and forcing me to select any date, i want to submit blank input.
Thanks.

Comment: I suppose you should remove `ng-required="false"`

Comment: it's not working, i have already tried

Comment: created [this fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/goueo40n/4/). Cannot reproduce it

Answer (score 0):

I know, it might be a little late, but maybe it's helping somebody else.

I assume your model variable is an empty string. I tried with tanmay's [fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/dr8ky07f/) and changed it a little.

When you change

```
$scope.user.availableFrom = "";
```

to

```
$scope.user.availableFrom = null;
```

or completely remove this line, it will work.